# Missing Configuration Properties in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to change the configuration properties of my project, but I can't seem to find the relevant properties.

Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Here is an image showing the missing properties:

[image: Image showing missing configuration properties]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's normal, because **you are viewing the properties of your solution, not the properties of your project** :)

This happens when your solution is selected, and not your project.

You have 2 options:

- Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer, and select "Properties"
- Select your project in the Solution Explorer, and then open `Project -> Properties`

Comment: Aaaaaah Thank you! :-)